# Python 3 Best practices on distinguish production and development configuration

Tags: python

I'm working on an embedded system project where my `dev` setup is different than my `prod`.
The differences include variables and packages imports.

What is the best way to structure the config files for python3 application where `dev` and `prod` setups are different?

`prod`: My device exchange messages (using [pyserial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/)) with an electronic system and also communicates with a server.

`dev`: I use a fake and fixed response from a function to mock both the electronic and server responses.
Even if the functions that I mock are essential in `prod` they are less in `dev`.
I can mock them because the most important part of this project are the functions that use and treat them.
So, there are packages imports and function calls that do not make sense and introduce errors in `dev` mode.

Every time I need to switch from one to another I need to change a good amount of the code and some times there are errors introduced. I know this is really () not the best approach and I wanted to know what are the **best practices**.

### The Closest Solution Found

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/396762) there is a good solution to set up different variables for each environment. I was hoping for something similar but for projects that require different packages import for different environments.

### My Setup

Basic workflow:

- A `task` thread is executed each second

  - `module_1` do work and call `module_2`
  - `module_2` do work and call `module_3`
  - `module_3` do work and send back a response

Basic folder structure:

- `root`

  - `main`
  - `config.py`
  - `/config`

    - `prod`
    - `dev`
  - `/mod_1`
  - `/mod_2`
  - `/mod_3`
  - `/replace_imports`

`module_1` and `module_3` use, each one, a specific package for `prod` and must be replaced by a `dev` function

What do I have:

```py
# config.py
if os.environ["app"] == "dev":
    import * from root.config.dev
if os.environ["app"] == "prod":
    import * from root.config.prod
```

```py
# config/prod.py
import _3rd_party_module_alpha
import _3rd_party_module_beta
...
obj_alpha = _3rd_party_module_alpha()
func_beta = _3rd_party_module_beta()
```

```py
# config/dev.py
import * from root.replace_imports
```

```py
# replace_imports.py
obj_alpha = fake_3rd_party_module_alpha()
func_beta = fake_3rd_party_module_beta()
```

Comment: I would argue importing your configuration as code is already a bad idea.

Comment: Also, it's `from <module> import *`, not `import * from <module>`. (And `from ... import *` is frowned upon as well.)

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Can you clarify *why* you need to import different modules? Or why there is such a clear distinction between prod and dev? What is the problem you are trying to solve with this setup? Usually, one can use production and development parts interchangeably, and even mix them. Having two distinct domains that cannot be mixed suggest that prod and dev have diverged, which defeats the point of having them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I edited my question to add as much detail possible. "Usually, one can use production and development parts interchangeably" this is exactly why I decided to post a question here. It is because I didn't find a solution to my problem. And I also believe I'm not the only one. "Having two distinct domains that cannot be mixed suggest that prod and dev have diverged, which defeats the point of having them", not in my case.

Comment: The obvious reason for prod and nonprod not matching is when you have external systems to call. Prod calls one URL that is tied to the live business function. Dev calls a different one that is used for testing of some sort but doesn't flow into the live business functions. (For example, if you order on Dev, nothing gets delivered.)

Answer (score 7):

You really should not have *code* changes between a dev at point X, and pushing into QA/CI , then prod at point X.  Your dev and prod code can be expected to be different at different stages, of course, and version control is key.  But moving to production should not require *code* changes, just *config* changes.

Environment variables (see [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) stuff) can help, but sometimes config is in code, for example in Django setting files.

In environments like Django where "it points to" a settings file, I've seen this kinda of stuff:

#### base_settings.py:

```
common config
```

#### dev_settings.py:

```
#top of file
import * from base_settings


... dev specifics, including overrides of base...
```

edit:  I am well aware of issues with `import *`.  First, this is a special case, for configurations, where you **want** to import everything.  Second, the real issue with `import *` is that it clobbers the current namespace.  That import is right at the top so that won't happen.  Linters aside, and they can be suppressed for just that line, the leftover issue is that you may not always know where a variable magically came from, unless you look in base.

#### prod_settings.py:

```
import * from base_settings

...production specifics, including overrides of base...
```

Advanced users of webpack configuration files (and those are *brutal*) do the same thing, i.e. use a **base.js** then import that into a **dev.js** and **prod.js**.

The key here is to have as much as possible in **base**, possibly with the help of environment variables (be careful not to over-rely on those, no ones likes apps with dozens of environment variable settings).  Then **dev** and **prod** are basically about keys, paths, urls, ports, that kind of stuff.  Make sure to keep secrets out of them however, because they gravitate there naturally but have no business being under version control.

#### re. your current code

```
appname = os.getenv("app")

if appname == "dev":

    #outside of base=>dev/prod merges, at top of "in-config" namespaces, 
    #I would avoid `import *` here and elsewhere

    import root.config.dev as config

elif appname == "prod":

    import root.config.prod as config

else:
    raise ValueError(f"environment variable $app should have been either `dev` or `prod`. got:{appname}:")
```

Last, if you are stuck without an "it points to Python settings file" mechanism, similar to that found in Django, you can (probably) roll your own by storing the config module path (`xxx.prod`,`xxx.dev`) in an environment variable and then using a dynamic import.  Mind you, your current code largely does that already except that you can't experiment with/add other settings files.

Don't worry if you don't get it right right away, and don't over-design up front - it takes a while to find what works best for you/your app.

Comment: "import * from foo" is usually best avoided; it makes a mess for linters.

Comment: generally, yes.  however, this is a special case for configurations.  of course, if you want to be dogmatic about it, go right ahead.  btw, the linters can be suppressed with directives.  `# pylint: disable=wildcard-import` then `# pylint: enable=wildcard-import`  and the real reason for it being an anti-pattern isn't linters, it's overwriting your namespace references inadvertently.

Answer (score 4):

[Pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) was specially created for these things and more

Comment: Check the amount of time since my answer was published - it's been almost 1.5 years, everything could changed

Comment: @rustyMagnet Why do you say it is dead? Last commit was 10 days ago.

Comment: @HectorOrdonez. You are correct. 
 I can see a good amount of recent commits. 
 I moved to Poetry.  But I was not alone thinking pipenv was retired:  https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/pipenv-is-dead-what-does-everyone-here-use-python-environments/595543

Comment: @rustyMagnet Thanks for sharing. Poetry seems well taken care of, might give it a try.

Comment: rustyMagenet is dead

Answer (score 3):

Use git branches (or mercurial or whatever version control system you're using - you *are* using a vcs, are you ?) and virtualenvs. That's exactly what they are for. Your config files should only be used for stuff like db connections identifiers, api keys etc.